# Standard deviation of less than one

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

How would I find the approximate percentage of values within a standard deviation of less than one on the normal model?

Chebyshev's rule is only used when the standard deviation is greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: I don't understand.  For a normal random variable, 68% of outcomes are expected to be within 1 standard deviation of the mean, for *any* standard deviation.  Why does Chebyshev enter into this?

Comment: Because Chebyshev's rule is a way to make a mathematical approximation. However, the problem resides in that fact that his rule only works with standard deviations of one or greater, while I'm interested in standard deviations of less than one.

Comment: But you don't need Chebyshev is my point. Why not simply use a table of normal percentiles and match them up to your standard deviation?  Just use the normal distribution directly.

Comment: Well I didn't know that was a thing...Put it as a nice-sounding answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You can rely on an approximation of the error function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Taylor_series

Comment: Your final sentence would be better written as *"Chebyshev's inequality is only useful when looking more than one standard deviation away from the expected value"*.  Though, as others have said, you can do better than Chebyshev's inequality if you know which distribution you have.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(Z < 1) = \alpha \approx 0.8413$$
$$P(Z > 1) = 1-\alpha = P(Z < -1)$$
$$P(-1 < Z < 1) = 1 - P(Z>1)-P(Z<-1)$$
$$P(-1 < Z < 1) = 1 - 2\cdot P(Z>1) = 1 - 2\cdot (1-\alpha)$$
$$P(-1 < Z < 1) = 2\alpha - 1 \approx 0.6826$$

Answer (score 0):

A normal model has about 62.8% of its values within 1 standard deviation of the mean, regardless of the standard deviation. [The wikipedia page for the first three standard deviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) has a nice picture.